# Как настроить навигационную цепочку в описании продукта?

Tags: php, битрикс

Внутри директории `catalog.section` добавил в файл `component_epilog.php` следующую строку:

```
$APPLICATION->AddChainItem($arResult['NAME']);
```

После этого навигационная цепочка продвинулась в каталог и стали отображаться разделы:

> Главная > Каталог > Раздел

Но при переходе к продукту она не изменяется. Подскажите, как привести навигационную цепочку к такому виду:

> Главная > Каталог > Раздел > Продукт

Comment: Потому что за вывод товара отвечает не `catalog.section`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То как вы делаете не верно. Если Вам нужно чтобы компонент `catalog.section` выводил название раздела в цепочку навигации, то установите "галку" параметру `"Включать раздел в цепочку навигации"` в его настройках или в коде подключения компонента установите значение параметра `'ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN'=>'Y'`. Чтобы отобразить название элемента Вам нужно настроить компонент `catalog.element`, в нем есть параметры: `Включать раздел в цепочку навигации` и `Включать название элемента в цепочку навигации` - установите им галки. Или в коде подключения компонента `catalog.element` пропишите `'ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN'=>'Y'`, `'ADD_ELEMENT_CHAIN'=>'Y'`.

Лучше всего конечно использовать комплексный компонент каталога и его настройки для отображения разделов и элементов в навигационной цепочке.

Читайте [документацию](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/) и [курсы](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/) по продукту прежде чем задавать вопросы и что-то делать.

Ссылки на документацию:

1. [Комплексный компонент `catalog`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/content/iblock/components_2/catalog/catalog.php)
2. [Элементы раздела `catalog.section`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/content/iblock/components_2/catalog/catalog_section.php)
3. [Элемент каталога детально `catalog.element`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/content/iblock/components_2/catalog/catalog_element.php)